# Custom Sine function using Taylor's Series in C (maybe C++ too)

Tags: c++, c, trigonometry

Here is a lil program i made for calculating sine with Tayilo's serires for a school assignment
i had. Does anyone have a better idea? I mean it works but it can be better

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(int argc, int **argv){
    system ("chcp 1253");
    int deg, i, a=(-1), flag=0;
    double pi=3.14159265359, x, sinx, o1, o2; //pi is rounded up to the last digit
    
    printf("Δώσε γωνία σε μοίρες από 0-2π (0-360):"); //translate: give angle in degrees
    scanf("%d",&deg);
    x=(pi/180)*deg; //apo moires se rad (metavlith x)
    o2=((x*x*x)/6)*a;
    sinx=x+o2;
    
    for(i=4; flag!=1; i+=2){
        o1=a*o2*((x*x)/(i*(i+1)));
        if (fabs(o2-o1)<=0.000001){
            flag=1;
        };
        sinx=sinx+o1;
        o2=o1;
    };
    
    printf("\nΤο ημίτονο του %d είναι: %f", deg, sinx); //the sine of %d is ...
    return 0;
};
```

There is nothing wrong with the code as my rookie eyes see, but im definetly sure it can be improved.

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ Sine taylor series optimal".  Always search the internet before posting to StackOverflow.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Comment: You should make a constant temporary variable: `const double x_squared = x * x;`  In your loop, replace `x * x` with `x_squared`.  No need to repeat the `x * x` calculation when the `x` variable doesn't change in the loop.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, use the `bool` type for `flag`, and the constants `true` or `false`.  No need to use the ancient method of 1 for true and zero for false.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews You can do that in C too.

Comment: And in C23, you won't even need to include `<stdbool.h>` to gain access to `bool`, `true`, `false` — they will be full keywords in Standard C.

Comment: It's a personal preference but you might try adding whitespace around operators for readability. `o1=a*o2*((x*x)/(i*(i+1)));` is too dense for me.

Comment: Define "better" as something exact and measurable. Do you want it to be faster?

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone have a better idea? I mean it works but it can be better

**Fails for 333°**

Expected "-0.453990", Received "-0.453991".  A simple loop of integer values [0-360] would have detected this.  IOWs, even simple test code better than "nothing wrong with the code as my rookie eyes" and pointed the need for smaller *epsilon*.

**Only handles integer values**

Took me a while to see this code does not report any input problem with non-integer input like 1.234,  Code needs better input validation.  As is, it give wrong results (e. g. the result of sine(1))

**Fails for large values**

"There is nothing wrong with the code as my rookie eyes" --> Try 3600 degrees.  If that is outside the range of acceptable input, report that range error.

**Very course**

Little reason for such a low precision result from a `double` function.

**Approximate π**

"pi is rounded up to the last digit" mis-states the *last digit*. There is no advantage in using such a rounded value.  `double` typically has 53-bits of precision.  Use at least 17 significant decimal digits for *machine* π.  Your system will use what it can.

```
// double pi=3.14159265359
double pi=3.1415926535897932384626433832795
```

**Its *floating* point**

`double` is encoded as *floating* point, not *fixed* point.  `fabs(o2-o1)<=0.000001` is a useful compare for *fixed* point algorithm.  Instead the terminating condition should approach the series ending from a *floating* point of view.

```
// fabs(o2-o1)<=0.000001
#define MY_EPSILON 0.000001
fabs(o2-o1)<= fabs(o1)*MY_EPSILON
```

I'd use a finer *epsilon*, maybe 1.0e-15 and avoid naked magic numbers.

Likewise `"%f"` reports with fixed number of places after the decimal point.  This reports 0.000000 for all tiny angles when the sine Taylor's series algorithm works very well for small angles.  Use `"%g"` or perhaps `"%.15g"` for more detail.  The `printf()` *precision* used here is related to the *epsilon* used above.

**Large values**

When the range is far from [-90...+90] degrees, the Taylor series converges slowly.  Use  trig identifies to bring the angle into [-45...+45] degree range.  Also code a `cosine()`  routine.

Range reduction as *radians* is tricky as π is an irrational number.  Therefore reduce the angle, in degrees first.  With `fmod()`, this is usually *exact*.

```
deg = fmod(deg, 360.0);
```

**Pedantic bug: -0.0**

For input -0.0, I'd expect an output of -0.000000 as `sine()` is a *odd* function instead of OP's 0.000000.

---

Sample alternative (untested, and still lacks range reduction other than [-360... +360] - something yet to do):

```
#include <math.h>
double sine(double x_degrees) {
  static const double d2r = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795 / 180.0;
// Bring x into the primary range
  x_degrees = fmod(x_degrees, 360.0);
   // To do: reduce to -45... 45 range.
  double x_radians = x_degrees * d2r;
  double x2 = x_radians * x_radians;
  double sum = 0.0;
  double term = x_radians;
  for (unsigned i = 1; ; i++); 
    double new_sum = sum + term;
    // If additional terms fail to change the sum, quit.
    if (new_sum == sum) {
      break;
    }
    sum = new_sum;
    term *= -x2 / ((2 * i) * (2 * i + 1));
  }
  return sum;
}
```

---

Once you get a better `sine()`, along with test code, post on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) for a deeper review.

Comment: Is it possible that `for (unsigned i = 1; ; i++);` loops round for a 16 bit `unsigned` on some values of `x_degrees` and you end up with division by zero? I'd be tempted to use `for (unsigned i = 1; i; ++i);`. My adjustment to `++i` is an old habit.

Comment: @Bathsheba With 16-bit or any bit width `unsigned`, I do not see division by zero happening once `|x_radians| <= pi/4` after all range reductions  (not all shown to leave some work for OP), as `term` becomes vanishingly small sooner.  Note problems occurs once `i > 127` or so, yet `term` should hit 0 long beforehand.

Comment: I'd love to spend time analysing this for all allowable floating point schemes for `double`, but alas no time.

Comment: And you have a point on `i > 127` - indeed the demoninator could overflow. `x2 / (2 * i) / (2 * i + 1);` is a subtle fix for that.

Comment: @Bathsheba True about `x2 / (2 * i) / (2 * i + 1)`, yet that I assert is not needed and adds another rounding - which I try to avoid to maintain accuracy. At `i == 33`, `sum + term` should make no difference even with 128-bit FP.

Comment: Main thing here though is that it's about time this answer was upvoted. Sorry!

Comment: @Bathsheba Professional exchange of ideas always appreciated.